# JavaScript only targets first element on page

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following script which I am trying to target any link with a class of `.button` to add a `<span>` tag around the text element. For example:

```
<a class="button" href="#">Read More</a>
```

Becomes

```
<a class="button" href="#"><span>Read More</span></a>
```

My script:

```
// insert span into anchor
"use strict";

var anchor = document.querySelector(".button");
var html = anchor.innerHTML;

anchor.innerHTML = "<span>" + html + "</span>";
```

This works, but only on the first instance of the page?

Comment: [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) vs [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

Comment: RTFM "The Document method querySelector() returns the first Element within the document that matches the specified selector". Nah just come to SO and ask a question and let others do your thinking for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should loop through all the elements using the ALL selector **[`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)** like :

```
var anchors = document.querySelectorAll(".button");

for( var i=0;i<anchors.length;i++){
     anchors[i].innerHTML = "<span>" + anchors[i].innerHTML + "</span>";
}
```

```js
var anchors = document.querySelectorAll(".button");

for (var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {
  anchors[i].innerHTML = "<span>" + anchors[i].innerHTML + "</span>";
}

console.log(document.body.innerHTML);
```

```html
<button class='button'>Read More</button>
<br>
<button class='button'>Read More</button>
<br>
<button class='button'>Read More</button>
```

Comment: Thanks, that's great. Would I need another script to target `inputs`?

Comment: Thanks to everyone, very helpful

Comment: Glad we could helps.

Answer (score 2):

[`querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) returns only the first matched element. To get all the elements from the page you have to use [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll). Then loop through all the element for the change to make:

```js
"use strict";

var anchor = document.querySelectorAll(".button");
anchor.forEach(function(a){
  a.innerHTML = "<span>" + a.textContent + "</span>";
});
```

```css
span{
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<a class="button" href="#">Home</a><br>
<a class="button" href="#">About Us</a><br>
<a class="button" href="#">Read More</a>
```