# Table layout with javascript and HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am new at Stackoverflow and am still learning: I've created the HTML table and I have a problem with the layout.  When I duplicate table it messes up my layout, look at a table with number 2, tables should look the same: the second table should look like table number 1

```js
var tbody = document.querySelector('tbody');
var thscoped = document.querySelector('tbody .sem');
var count = 0;
for (var ch = tbody.firstChild; ch; ch = ch.nextSibling)
  if (ch instanceof HTMLElement) count++;

thscoped.setAttribute("rowspan", count);
```

```css
.sem {
  border:1px solid red
}
```

```html
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="responsive-table  table-bordered ">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">Year</th>
        <th scope="col">Short</th>
        <th scope="col">Exam</th>
        <th scope="col">P</th>
        <th scope="col">S</th>
        <th scope="col">A</th>
        <th scope="col">SJ</th>
        <th scope="col">TJ</th>
        <th scope="col">PK</th>
        <th scope="col">ECTS</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th class="sem" scope="row">1</th>
        <td data-title="Short">Lor</td>
        <td data-title="Exam">Lorem</td>
        <td data-title="P">4</td>
        <td data-title="S">4</td>
        <td data-title="A">0</td>
        <td data-title="SJ">0</td>
        <td data-title="TJ">0</td>
        <td data-title="PK">0</td>
        <td data-title="ECTS">0</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td data-title="Short">MATM</td>
        <td data-title="Exam">Lorem (1/2)</td>
        <td data-title="P">4</td>
        <td data-title="S">4</td>
        <td data-title="A">0</td>
        <td data-title="SJ">0</td>
        <td data-title="TJ">0</td>
        <td data-title="PK">0</td>
        <td data-title="ECTS">0</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td data-title="Short">MATM</td>
        <td data-title="Exam">Lorem (1/2)</td>
        <td data-title="P">4</td>
        <td data-title="S">4</td>
        <td data-title="A">0</td>
        <td data-title="SJ">0</td>
        <td data-title="TJ">0</td>
        <td data-title="PK">0</td>
        <td data-title="ECTS">0</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td data-title="Short">MATM</td>
        <td data-title="Exam">Lorem</td>
        <td data-title="P">4</td>
        <td data-title="S">4</td>
        <td data-title="A">0</td>
        <td data-title="SJ">0</td>
        <td data-title="TJ">0</td>
        <td data-title="PK">0</td>
        <td data-title="ECTS">0</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td data-title="Short">MATM</td>
        <td data-title="Exam">Lorem (1/2)
        </td>
        <td data-title="P">4</td>
        <td data-title="S">4</td>
        <td data-title="A">0</td>
        <td data-title="SJ">0</td>
        <td data-title="TJ">0</td>
        <td data-title="PK">0</td>
        <td data-title="ECTS">0</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td data-title="Short">MATM</td>
        <td data-title="Exam">Lorem (1/2)</td>
        <td data-title="P">4</td>
        <td data-title="S">4</td>
        <td data-title="A">0</td>
        <td data-title="SJ">0</td>
        <td data-title="TJ">0</td>
        <td data-title="PK">0</td>
        <td data-title="ECTS">0</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td data-title="Short">MATM</td>
        <td data-title="Exam">Lorem (1/2)</td>
        <td data-title="P">4</td>
        <td data-title="S">4</td>
        <td data-title="A">0</td>
        <td data-title="SJ">0</td>
        <td data-title="TJ">0</td>
        <td data-title="PK">0</td>
        <td data-title="ECTS">0</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td data-title="Short">-</td>
        <td data-title="Exam">Lorem: 1</td>
        <td data-title="P">-</td>
        <td data-title="S">-</td>
        <td data-title="A">-</td>
        <td data-title="SJ">-</td>
        <td data-title="TJ">-</td>
        <td data-title="PK">-</td>
        <td data-title="ECTS">-
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td data-title="Short">-</td>
        <td data-title="Exam">Lorem: 1</td>
        <td data-title="P">-</td>
        <td data-title="S">-</td>
        <td data-title="A">-</td>
        <td data-title="SJ">-</td>
        <td data-title="TJ">-</td>
        <td data-title="PK">-</td>
        <td data-title="ECTS">-
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="responsive-table  table-bordered ">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">Year</th>
        <th scope="col">Short</th>
        <th scope="col">Exam</th>
        <th scope="col">P</th>
        <th scope="col">S</th>
        <th scope="col">A</th>
        <th scope="col">SJ</th>
        <th scope="col">TJ</th>
        <th scope="col">PK</th>
        <th scope="col">ECTS</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th class="sem" scope="row">1</th>
        <td data-title="Short">Lor</td>
        <td data-title="Exam">Lorem</td>
        <td data-title="P">4</td>
        <td data-title="S">4</td>
        <td data-title="A">0</td>
        <td data-title="SJ">0</td>
        <td data-title="TJ">0</td>
        <td data-title="PK">0</td>
        <td data-title="ECTS">0</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td data-title="Short">MATM</td>
        <td data-title="Exam">Lorem (1/2)</td>
        <td data-title="P">4</td>
        <td data-title="S">4</td>
        <td data-title="A">0</td>
        <td data-title="SJ">0</td>
        <td data-title="TJ">0</td>
        <td data-title="PK">0</td>
        <td data-title="ECTS">0</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td data-title="Short">MATM</td>
        <td data-title="Exam">Lorem (1/2)</td>
        <td data-title="P">4</td>
        <td data-title="S">4</td>
        <td data-title="A">0</td>
        <td data-title="SJ">0</td>
        <td data-title="TJ">0</td>
        <td data-title="PK">0</td>
        <td data-title="ECTS">0</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td data-title="Short">MATM</td>
        <td data-title="Exam">Lorem</td>
        <td data-title="P">4</td>
        <td data-title="S">4</td>
        <td data-title="A">0</td>
        <td data-title="SJ">0</td>
        <td data-title="TJ">0</td>
        <td data-title="PK">0</td>
        <td data-title="ECTS">0</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td data-title="Short">MATM</td>
        <td data-title="Exam">Lorem (1/2)
        </td>
        <td data-title="P">4</td>
        <td data-title="S">4</td>
        <td data-title="A">0</td>
        <td data-title="SJ">0</td>
        <td data-title="TJ">0</td>
        <td data-title="PK">0</td>
        <td data-title="ECTS">0</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td data-title="Short">MATM</td>
        <td data-title="Exam">Lorem (1/2)</td>
        <td data-title="P">4</td>
        <td data-title="S">4</td>
        <td data-title="A">0</td>
        <td data-title="SJ">0</td>
        <td data-title="TJ">0</td>
        <td data-title="PK">0</td>
        <td data-title="ECTS">0</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td data-title="Short">MATM</td>
        <td data-title="Exam">Lorem (1/2)</td>
        <td data-title="P">4</td>
        <td data-title="S">4</td>
        <td data-title="A">0</td>
        <td data-title="SJ">0</td>
        <td data-title="TJ">0</td>
        <td data-title="PK">0</td>
        <td data-title="ECTS">0</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td data-title="Short">-</td>
        <td data-title="Exam">Lorem: 1</td>
        <td data-title="P">-</td>
        <td data-title="S">-</td>
        <td data-title="A">-</td>
        <td data-title="SJ">-</td>
        <td data-title="TJ">-</td>
        <td data-title="PK">-</td>
        <td data-title="ECTS">-
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td data-title="Short">-</td>
        <td data-title="Exam">Lorem: 1</td>
        <td data-title="P">-</td>
        <td data-title="S">-</td>
        <td data-title="A">-</td>
        <td data-title="SJ">-</td>
        <td data-title="TJ">-</td>
        <td data-title="PK">-</td>
        <td data-title="ECTS">-
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript only targets first element on page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51290728/javascript-only-targets-first-element-on-page)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've just worked with the first tbody at your Javascript code. Let's try this.

```js
var tbody = document.querySelectorAll('tbody');


tbody.forEach(function(bdy){
 let thscoped = bdy.querySelector('.sem');
 var count = 0;
    for (var ch = bdy.firstChild; ch; ch = ch.nextSibling)
      if (ch instanceof HTMLElement) count++;

    thscoped.setAttribute("rowspan", count);

});
```

```css
.sem {
     border:1px solid red
}
```

```html
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="responsive-table  table-bordered ">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">Year</th>
        <th scope="col">Short</th>
        <th scope="col">Exam</th>
        <th scope="col">P</th>
        <th scope="col">S</th>
        <th scope="col">A</th>
        <th scope="col">SJ</th>
        <th scope="col">TJ</th>
        <th scope="col">PK</th>
        <th scope="col">ECTS</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th class="sem" scope="row">1</th>
        <td data-title="Short">Lor</td>
        <td data-title="Exam">Lorem</td>
        <td data-title="P">4</td>
        <td data-title="S">4</td>
        <td data-title="A">0</td>
        <td data-title="SJ">0</td>
        <td data-title="TJ">0</td>
        <td data-title="PK">0</td>
        <td data-title="ECTS">0</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td data-title="Short">MATM</td>
        <td data-title="Exam">Lorem (1/2)</td>
        <td data-title="P">4</td>
        <td data-title="S">4</td>
        <td data-title="A">0</td>
        <td data-title="SJ">0</td>
        <td data-title="TJ">0</td>
        <td data-title="PK">0</td>
        <td data-title="ECTS">0</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td data-title="Short">MATM</td>
        <td data-title="Exam">Lorem (1/2)</td>
        <td data-title="P">4</td>
        <td data-title="S">4</td>
        <td data-title="A">0</td>
        <td data-title="SJ">0</td>
        <td data-title="TJ">0</td>
        <td data-title="PK">0</td>
        <td data-title="ECTS">0</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td data-title="Short">MATM</td>
        <td data-title="Exam">Lorem</td>
        <td data-title="P">4</td>
        <td data-title="S">4</td>
        <td data-title="A">0</td>
        <td data-title="SJ">0</td>
        <td data-title="TJ">0</td>
        <td data-title="PK">0</td>
        <td data-title="ECTS">0</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td data-title="Short">MATM</td>
        <td data-title="Exam">Lorem (1/2)
        </td>
        <td data-title="P">4</td>
        <td data-title="S">4</td>
        <td data-title="A">0</td>
        <td data-title="SJ">0</td>
        <td data-title="TJ">0</td>
        <td data-title="PK">0</td>
        <td data-title="ECTS">0</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td data-title="Short">MATM</td>
        <td data-title="Exam">Lorem (1/2)</td>
        <td data-title="P">4</td>
        <td data-title="S">4</td>
        <td data-title="A">0</td>
        <td data-title="SJ">0</td>
        <td data-title="TJ">0</td>
        <td data-title="PK">0</td>
        <td data-title="ECTS">0</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td data-title="Short">MATM</td>
        <td data-title="Exam">Lorem (1/2)</td>
        <td data-title="P">4</td>
        <td data-title="S">4</td>
        <td data-title="A">0</td>
        <td data-title="SJ">0</td>
        <td data-title="TJ">0</td>
        <td data-title="PK">0</td>
        <td data-title="ECTS">0</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td data-title="Short">-</td>
        <td data-title="Exam">Lorem: 1</td>
        <td data-title="P">-</td>
        <td data-title="S">-</td>
        <td data-title="A">-</td>
        <td data-title="SJ">-</td>
        <td data-title="TJ">-</td>
        <td data-title="PK">-</td>
        <td data-title="ECTS">-
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td data-title="Short">-</td>
        <td data-title="Exam">Lorem: 1</td>
        <td data-title="P">-</td>
        <td data-title="S">-</td>
        <td data-title="A">-</td>
        <td data-title="SJ">-</td>
        <td data-title="TJ">-</td>
        <td data-title="PK">-</td>
        <td data-title="ECTS">-
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="responsive-table  table-bordered ">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">Year</th>
        <th scope="col">Short</th>
        <th scope="col">Exam</th>
        <th scope="col">P</th>
        <th scope="col">S</th>
        <th scope="col">A</th>
        <th scope="col">SJ</th>
        <th scope="col">TJ</th>
        <th scope="col">PK</th>
        <th scope="col">ECTS</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th class="sem" scope="row">1</th>
        <td data-title="Short">Lor</td>
        <td data-title="Exam">Lorem</td>
        <td data-title="P">4</td>
        <td data-title="S">4</td>
        <td data-title="A">0</td>
        <td data-title="SJ">0</td>
        <td data-title="TJ">0</td>
        <td data-title="PK">0</td>
        <td data-title="ECTS">0</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td data-title="Short">MATM</td>
        <td data-title="Exam">Lorem (1/2)</td>
        <td data-title="P">4</td>
        <td data-title="S">4</td>
        <td data-title="A">0</td>
        <td data-title="SJ">0</td>
        <td data-title="TJ">0</td>
        <td data-title="PK">0</td>
        <td data-title="ECTS">0</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td data-title="Short">MATM</td>
        <td data-title="Exam">Lorem (1/2)</td>
        <td data-title="P">4</td>
        <td data-title="S">4</td>
        <td data-title="A">0</td>
        <td data-title="SJ">0</td>
        <td data-title="TJ">0</td>
        <td data-title="PK">0</td>
        <td data-title="ECTS">0</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td data-title="Short">MATM</td>
        <td data-title="Exam">Lorem</td>
        <td data-title="P">4</td>
        <td data-title="S">4</td>
        <td data-title="A">0</td>
        <td data-title="SJ">0</td>
        <td data-title="TJ">0</td>
        <td data-title="PK">0</td>
        <td data-title="ECTS">0</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td data-title="Short">MATM</td>
        <td data-title="Exam">Lorem (1/2)
        </td>
        <td data-title="P">4</td>
        <td data-title="S">4</td>
        <td data-title="A">0</td>
        <td data-title="SJ">0</td>
        <td data-title="TJ">0</td>
        <td data-title="PK">0</td>
        <td data-title="ECTS">0</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td data-title="Short">MATM</td>
        <td data-title="Exam">Lorem (1/2)</td>
        <td data-title="P">4</td>
        <td data-title="S">4</td>
        <td data-title="A">0</td>
        <td data-title="SJ">0</td>
        <td data-title="TJ">0</td>
        <td data-title="PK">0</td>
        <td data-title="ECTS">0</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td data-title="Short">MATM</td>
        <td data-title="Exam">Lorem (1/2)</td>
        <td data-title="P">4</td>
        <td data-title="S">4</td>
        <td data-title="A">0</td>
        <td data-title="SJ">0</td>
        <td data-title="TJ">0</td>
        <td data-title="PK">0</td>
        <td data-title="ECTS">0</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td data-title="Short">-</td>
        <td data-title="Exam">Lorem: 1</td>
        <td data-title="P">-</td>
        <td data-title="S">-</td>
        <td data-title="A">-</td>
        <td data-title="SJ">-</td>
        <td data-title="TJ">-</td>
        <td data-title="PK">-</td>
        <td data-title="ECTS">-
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td data-title="Short">-</td>
        <td data-title="Exam">Lorem: 1</td>
        <td data-title="P">-</td>
        <td data-title="S">-</td>
        <td data-title="A">-</td>
        <td data-title="SJ">-</td>
        <td data-title="TJ">-</td>
        <td data-title="PK">-</td>
        <td data-title="ECTS">-
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: For further reference, see [Document.querySelector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector): "The Document method querySelector() returns the *first Element* within the document that matches the specified selector, or group of selectors." Compare with [Document.querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).

Answer (score 1):

You have two `tbody` elements, but `var tbody = document.querySelector('tbody');` only gets the first. You need to get them all and loop over them.